# Map keys with the same name

Tags: ruby, json, dictionary

A GET to an API endpoint I'm working with returns json with an inconsistent order of contacts, either

```
{"contacts"=>[
  {"id"=>$UUID_0, "name"=>nil, "email"=>$EMAIL_0, "phone"=>$PHONE_0, "type"=>"foo"},
  {"id"=>$UUID_1, "name"=>nil, "email"=>$EMAIL_1, "phone"=>$PHONE_1, "type"=>"bar"}
]}
```

or

```
{"contacts"=>[
  {"id"=>$UUID_1, "name"=>nil, "email"=>$EMAIL_1, "phone"=>$PHONE_1, "type"=>"bar"},
  {"id"=>$UUID_0, "name"=>nil, "email"=>$EMAIL_0, "phone"=>$PHONE_0, "type"=>"foo"}
]}
```

The `"type"` values are the only static objects in these responses, so I'd like to map this so that the contact types are keys containing the other pairs:

```
{
  "foo"=>{"id"=>$UUID_0, "name"=>$NAME_0, "email"=>$EMAIL_0, "phone"=>$PHONE_0},
  "bar"=>{"id"=>$UUID_1, "name"=>$NAME_1, "email"=>$EMAIL_1, "phone"=>$PHONE_1}
}
```

A solution is not obvious to me.

Comment: See [Enumerable#group_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by)

Comment: Where does `$NAME_0`, `$NAME_1` come from?

Comment: `$NAME` is a randomly generated string for contact names, as are the rest of the non `"type"` values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Hash[data['contacts'].map { |c| [c['type'], c] }]
```

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks, Kyle.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Ruby on Rails, or at least ActiveSupport, you can try `index_by` instead of `group_by`: it won't put the values into arrays.

```
hash['contacts'].index_by {|r| r['type']}
=>
{
  "bar" => {
    "id"    => "asdf",
    "name"  => nil,
    "email" => "EMAIL_1",
    "phone" => "PHONE_1",
    "type"  => "bar"
  },
  "foo" => {
    "id"    => "asdf",
    "name"  => nil,
    "email" => "EMAIL_0",
    "phone" => "PHONE_0",
    "type"  => "foo"
  }
}
```

Comment: Sadly I'm using neither, though this seems ideal. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with Enumerable#reduce:

```
hash['contacts'].reduce({}) {|m,c| m[c['type']] = c;m}
```

How it works:

1. An empty hash is the starting point.
2. The block is called once for each element in the contacts list. The block receives the hash that we're building as `m` and the current contact as `c`.
3. In the block, assign `c` to the hash based on its `type` and return the hash so far.
4. Final result is the last return value of the block.

Comment: I suggest you use [Enumerable#each_with_object](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object), rather than `reduce`, to get rid of that pesky `;m`.

Comment: Alternatively, you could keep `reduce` and change the block to `{ |g,h| g.update({ h['type'] => h }) }` (a.k.a. `merge!`).